# object oriented javascript and IE7 issue

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function fake()
{
var ffake;
}

fake.prototype.abc = function()
{
   fake.ffake = 1;//not working in IE7 but seems to be working in all others
}

var myNewObject = new fake();
```

Because of the script is breaking on that instant, can not move forward.

firstly i am not getting reason and then i spend almost more then 2 hrs on google to figure out the solution.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing:

```
fake.ffake = 1;
```

To:

```
this.ffake = 1;
```

**Example:**

```
function fake()
{
  var ffake;
}

fake.prototype.abc = function()
{
   this.ffake = 1;
   alert(this.ffake);
}

var myNewObject = new fake();  
myNewObject.abc(); // alerts "1"
```

Comment: ups, thanks a lot..! actually i tried `this.ffake` as well but still Aptana(IDE) was showing the error so i switched to `fake.ffake = 1`.

Your solution is working.!